# Character (') is getting invalid when entered on phone (Tutor lms)

Tags: wordpress

Tutor lms fill in the blank problem I have problem like this in tutor lms fill in the blank. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNB2f.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z2aq.jpg)

I want the phone to accept (') as a valid answer when I type that character too. Please help me!

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to Tutor LMS' support team? If not then it might be a good idea to try, they should be able to help you figure out what the problem is: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/tutor/